# Extracting Pdf elements using .net

Tags: .net, pdf, acrobat, object-model, pdf-parsing

Looking for a free/paid .net library to extract the text/graphic/image elements of a given Acrobat (.pdf) document preferably as an object model so that we can translate it into another format that is understandable to a proprietary WYSIWYG editor.

If a direct translation is impossible would like to see what possible approaches can be taken to grab the text elements, shapes/graphics, images separately. The target format requires the elements being positioned explicitly using x,y positions on a page and it would be necessary for the PDF extraction library to tell me the co-ordinates of the parsed elements within a page.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Docotic.Pdf library](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/) for the task.

The library can [extract text from PDFs](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/pdf-text/extract) and provide information about coordinates of each word or even character. And it can [extract images from PDF documents](https://github.com/BitMiracle/Docotic.Pdf.Samples/tree/master/Samples/Images/ExtractImageCoordinates) while providing information about image position, size and transformations.

Disclaimer: I work for the vendor of the library.